# Ionic-native contacts “plugin_not_installed”

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am using devApp and the @ionic-native/contacts plugin keeps telling me that the plugin is not installed, but I am sure it is.
Here is the code sample:

```
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';


  export class ContactPage {
  everybody;
  constructor(public callNumber: CallNumber, public contacts: Contacts) {
    this.everybody = this.contacts.find(["*"]);
  }
```

Here i want simple fetch contact from android ionic 3.
can any one suggest me how to solve?
The error is

```
Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not _installed
```

Comment: Did you use `ionic cordova plugin add <pulgin>` command before your code implementation?

Comment: @R.Viral yes i have already added ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts ..but not working

Comment: also added in app.module.ts file right?

Comment: @R.Viral alreday added in app.module.ts  providers: [ Contacts]

Comment: Can you explain your steps of adding this pulgin, and one more thing can you change access modifier public to private for contact.

Comment: @R.Viral i have added these steps by following https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184809/discussion-between-manoj-maharana-and-r-viral).

Comment: can u try with platform.ready() ?

Comment: @kevalnayak platform.ready() can you explain?

Comment: @kevalnayak i have tried on platform.ready method also same error

Comment: hope u r test in real device

Comment: @kevalnayak yes i have test in real device

Comment: try in another function instead constructor  or page.

Comment: @kevalnayak can you provide some demo code or instruction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184815/discussion-between-keval-nayak-and-manoj-maharana).

Comment: is there any one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular"; 


  export class ContactPage {
  everybody;
  constructor(public callNumber: CallNumber, public contacts: Contacts, public plt:Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource)=>{
      this.everybody = this.contacts.find(["*"]);
    });    
  }
```

Note : All ionic native plugin are available after platform ready event.